# Transfer a large amount of PDF files from PC to Adobe Reader (on iPad)

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, pdf, books

I've a bunch (~200) of PDFs, organized in directories, (Topic wise), that I need to transfer to my iPad for offline reading.

I've two problems: First, emailing is not an option. These are around 720 megabytes in size, and the current connection I'm on is barely able to download 40 megabytes in half an hour. Besides, I could try GZIP compression, but I don't know if Adobe Acrobat can handle GZIP files.

Secondly, I would like to retain the directory structure of my documents.

I want to transfer all these PDFs to the Acrobat Reader on my iPad. I looked online and I'm told that under the Apps section of my iTunes library I must find "Acrobat Reader" and continue from there. I don't see anything in my iPad's Apps Library on the iTunes store!

I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

(I'm running on Windows 10, btw)

Comment: Do you necessarily need Acrobat Reader? There are many other apps that support file transfer via iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of iTunes removed much of the abilities to upload directly to an app.

While I don't know a shortcy, you could upload the files in one of two ways (making sure your device is connected via USB for the quickest upload).

- A Personal favourite is WALTR, but it's a paid option. You just drag your media into the Waltr screen and it uploads it. It will go to iBooks, however (I'm not sure about your specific requirement about Adobe Reader).
- Something more apt could be to copy the files into the files section that's created when you have the iCloud Windows app from Apple and upload the files into a folder there. I'm certain (but do not actually know) that you can then open the files using the file browser within Adobe reader, or the sharing function from the Files app on your device.

I really hope this helps give some guidance.